# what is the main point of DBpedia creation?

Tags: dbpedia

I misunderstand the main point.i read many paper and want to sure from point.are the steps of creating DBpedia by mapping the property and its value in ontology?
best regards

Answer (score 0):

Stack Overflow is for programming questions, which this is not. If you want to learn and understand more about DBpedia, I suggest you start with [the DBpedia website](http://dbpedia.org/), and [discussion list](https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/dbpedia-discussion).